# Trying to deserialize Json object passed in body

Tags: json, api, asp.net-core

I'm kind of a fresher when it comes to doing API work especially with JSON.

Here's what my code looks like...

Endpoing:

```
 [HttpPost("postWithBody")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> PostWithBody (string param1, [FromBody] object requestBody)
 {
     
     var x = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ParamModel>(requestBody); <-- Error cannot convert from 'object' to System.ReadOnlySpan<byte>
       
     return ok(param1); <--this here just so it doesn't bark at me

 }
```

SO in the above code, I'm erroring out on `(RequestBody)` with this error:

> Error cannot convert from 'object' to System.ReadOnlySpan

```
 public class ParamModel
 {
       public string PName {get;set;}
       public string PValue {get;set;}
 }
```

But essentially to finish the demo of what I'm trying to accomplish is, goal is to pass JSON value to this endpoint in the body that looks like this:

```
{
    "Param1": "XXX",
    "Param2": "111"
}
```

and my goal would be for CustomParams model class to have the

```
   PName = Param1
   PValue = "XXX"
```

and

```
   PName  = "Param2"
   PValue = "111"
```

Is this the correct approach I'm taking?

Thank you.

EDIT: I guess I could do something like: [FromBody] ParamModel requestBody

and I did try it, when I pass JSON like this, it came as null in the endpoint:

```
{"test":"hey"}
```

But also, I probably would need to do something like this, since I want to have the option of passing multiple params.

```
 public class ParamList
 {
    public List<ParamModel> data {get;set;}
 }
```

and have that be [FromBody] ParamList requestBody

Comment: Have you tried defining a DTO (poco class of your desired input from the body) and just using this DTO in  [FromBody] iso object?
It should deserialize automatically

Comment: Why are you doing `object requestBody` instead of just letting the framework deserialise for you? e.g. `ParamModel requestBody`

Comment: @DavidG see edit

Comment: Your JSON still needs to match the model, so you would need to pass something like this:  `{ "PName": "test", "PValue": "hey" }`

Comment: And if you want to use the `ParamList` object you just added, it would need to look like `{"data": [{ "PName": "test1", "PValue": "hey1" }, { "PName": "test2", "PValue": "hey2" }]}`

Comment: @DavidG awesome, thank you. I got this to work. Another problem that I have it when I use [FromBody] ParamList requestBody, I am not able to loop through the requestBody because ParamList does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumarator'. Of course this is beyond my question. But if this is something easy to answer. And by the way, please do post your comments as answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would suggest that you use the model in the action parameter and let the framework do the deserialisation for you:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostWithBody(
    string param1, [FromBody] ParamModel requestBody)
```

Now you will be able to post JSON in that matches that object, something like this for example:

```
{ 
    "PName": "test", 
    "PValue": "hey"
}
```

In your update, you say that you would like instead to use the `ParamList` object. In that case, you would need JSON that matches, something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        { "PName": "test1", "PValue": "hey1" }, 
        { "PName": "test2", "PValue": "hey2" }
    ]
}
```

Now in your action you can loop over the list like this:

```
foreach(var param in requestBody.data)
{
    var paramName = param.PName;
    var paramValue = param.PValue;
    // etc.
}
```